# How do i transfer specific records from a db to another

Tags: sql-server, data-transfer

i have the need to split my current database in two by selecting specific records of specific tables on the "source" db and copy exactly as the are (i.e. primary keys included) to the "target db".

i'm looking for some tool that allows me to do that. otherwise i have to build one on my own.

i'm using sql server

Comment: If it's not a problem to generate schema scripts from Management Studio, further actions are not difficult. SQL supports cross-database queries since 2012 if I'm not mistaken. So you can write something like INSERT INTO [NewDatabase] AS SELECT FROM [OldDatabase] WHERE <Any conditions you need>.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a one-time thing, make a backup and restore it as new database and start deleting the records in one db or the other.

Otherwise there is always the option to insert records with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <Table> ON`.

You can also let the whole database be scripted including data (or parts of it) in the SQL Management Studio: Right-Mouse on Database, Tasks, Generate Scripts, (choose what, next), Advanced, Types of data to script=Schema and data...